# Exception while executing function: SendMessagesToAzureSql. Core .Net SqlClient Data Provide

Tags: sql-server, azure-functions, postman

My Azure function call an Stored Procedure to Insert/Update in the DB!
when I EXEC my Stored Procedure in MSSMS it's work and i can see my table updated or insert  the  row,
But when in send it from my postMan ( To simulate in local) I got this error :

**An error occurred while processing request : 'Procedure or function usp_upsert_table1 has too many arguments specified.'
Executed 'SendToAzureSql' (Failed, Id=28xxx-fcxx-xxx-bxx-xxx, Duration=45091ms)
[2021-02-26T12:42:55.737Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: SendToAzureSql. Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Procedure or function usp_upsert_table1 has too many arguments specified**.

Below my StoredProcedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ usp_upsert_table1]
  (
   @Json NVARCHAR(MAX)
   )
    AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN

        WITH JsonToTable AS --recupere les elmt pour la requete
        (
            SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@Json) WITH (
                [version] [nvarchar](3),
                [type] [nvarchar](100), 
                [time] [nvarchar](28), 
                [datacontenttype] [nvarchar](32),
                [Application] [varchar](50) '$.data.Application',
                [ID] [varchar](10)'$.data.ID'

                  ....   
     )
```

EXEC of the Stored Procedure:

```
   DECLARE  @return_value int

   EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[ usp_upsert_table1]
    @Json = N'
    { 
    "version" : "1.0",
    "type" : "xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.table1",
    "id" : "Axx-12xx-xx4",
    "time" : "2018-04-05 17:31:00",
    "datacontenttype" : "application/json",
    "data" :          
             { "Application":"xx","ID":"xx-100","Code":"2", }
        }'
```

And this is exactly what i put in my PostMan Body:

```
{ 
    "version" : "1.0",
    "type" : "xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.table1",
    "source" : "xxx",
    "id" : "Axx-12xx-xx4",
    "time" : "2018-04-05 17:31:00",
    "datacontenttype" : "application/json",
    "data" :          
             { "Application":"xx","ID":"xx-100","Code":"2", }
        }'
```

this is my Azure fonction :

```
 namespace TriggerFunctions
{
 public static class SendToAzureSql
 {    
  private static readonly string AZURE_TABLE1= 
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TABLE1"); 

// Handler
private static AzureSqlHandler azSqlHandler;

[FunctionName("SendToAzureSql")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    string procedureName = "";
    try
    {
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
        {
            return new BadRequestResult();
        }
        dynamic message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        if (message == null)
        {
            return new BadRequestResult();
        }
        log.LogInformation((string)message.type.ToString()+ " : Process in progress...");
        switch (message.type.ToString())
        {                   
            case "xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.table1":
                procedureName = "usp_upsert_table1 ";
                InitHandlers(log, AZURE_TABLE1);
                break;
          
        }

        var dataJson = JsonDocument.Parse(requestBody);
        string actionType = message.type.ToString().Contains("deleted") ? "Deleted": "Default";
        await azSqlHandler.UpsertItemAsync(procedureName, actionType, payload: 
     dataJson.RootElement);
       
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.LogError($"An error occurred while processing request : '{e.Message}'");
        throw e;
    }
}

    private static void InitHandlers(ILogger log, string connectionString)
{
    // Create handler
    azSqlHandler = new AzureSqlHandler(log, connectionString);
```

Comment: Yes please, share some code

Comment: In addition to the function code, include at least the proc header with the parameter declarations.

Comment: @DanGuzman,@Roman I edit my question

Comment: Where is the `AzureSqlHandler.UpsertItemAsync` code? The error is in the proc call and we need to see it.

Comment: That's right !! It's works with me the error was that i forget to add a parametre in my stored procedure

Comment: Hi @nada, glad to hear that you have solved the issue and found the cause. I help you post it as answer. you can think about accept it as answer. Others could know the issue is resolved and this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for @Dan Guzman's comment. It helped you so much.

We are glad to hear that you have solved the issue and found the cause: "forget to add a parameter in my stored procedure".

I help you post it as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.